# ¿Cómo puede guardar cada iteración de un ciclo for en una variable con R?

Tags: r, funciones, variables, bucles

Cómo consigo hacer que cada iteración de un ciclo for se guarde en una variable ya sea como lista o data frame, dentro de una función.
Ya que posteriormente pueda llamar la función y que me devuelva esa nueva lista de iteraciones

```
direcciones_apis<-function(simbolos){
  for (ticker in simbolos){
    api_key<-'AA820F3E8D40E9D3'
    funcion<-'INCOME_STATEMENT'
    link<-str_c("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=",funcion,"&symbol=",ticker,"&apikey=",api_key)
    print(link)
    
    
}
  #Como devolver un dataframe o lista de cada iteraciones del ciclo for 
}

simbolos<-c('SPCE', 'MS',   'AL',   'MG',   'NVDA',     'ROKU', 'F',    'GO',   'GEO',
         'STL','KO',    'AM',   'GE',   'GME', 'BABA', 'CRSR', 'WISH',
         'PG',  'PEP',  'NKE',  'QS',   'PLTR', 'NIO',  'GS',   'HITI', 'MU')

direcciones_apis(simbolos)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma es generando un i que recorra tu vector de símbolos y cada concatenacion la guarde en una lista que inicialmente este vacia

```
direcciones_apis<-function(simbolos) {
  lista_variables = list()
  for (i in 1:length(simbolos)){
    ticker = simbolos[i]
    api_key<-'AA820F3E8D40E9D3'
    funcion<-'INCOME_STATEMENT'
    link<-str_c("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=",funcion,"&symbol=",ticker,"&apikey=",api_key)
    print(link)
    lista_variables[[i]] = link
  }
return(lista_variables)
}

simbolos<-c('SPCE', 'MS',   'AL',   'MG',   'NVDA',     'ROKU', 'F',    'GO',   'GEO',
            'STL','KO',    'AM',   'GE',   'GME', 'BABA', 'CRSR', 'WISH',
            'PG',  'PEP',  'NKE',  'QS',   'PLTR', 'NIO',  'GS',   'HITI', 'MU')

lista_variables = direcciones_apis(simbolos)
```

Usando programación funcional como es el uso de los map o lapply de R base
podrías hacer lo siguiente para que tu codigo quede mas compacto

```
direcciones_apis2 <- function(simbolos)
{
  api_key<-'AA820F3E8D40E9D3'
  funcion<-'INCOME_STATEMENT'
  
  lista = simbolos %>% 
    map(~str_c("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=",funcion,"&symbol=",.,"&apikey=",api_key))
  return(lista)

}

lista_variables2 = direcciones_apis2(simbolos)
```

con el map a cada elemento de simbolos le aplicamos la funcion str_c, donde retorna una lista con cada link creado

Comment: Impresionante, me fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta, la verdad es que estoy aprendiendo a programar todavía, pero veo que usando programación funcional reduzco bastantes líneas de código.